# Corda RPC connection on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, corda, cordite

I bootstrapped a Corda network with Cordite network map service following [official instructions](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/blob/master/FAQ.md). Everything, including SpringBoot server, works fine locally when nodes are deployed in Docker containers. But when I put the corda nodes in Kubernetes, SpringBoot server cannot communicate with Corda node. **In Docker setup, I'm dropped into corda console but in Kubernetes the console doesn't appear** (no error though; everything same except the console). There is probably some issues with RPC communication. Can anyone with experience point what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inter pod-communication in Kubernetes works differently from docker container's communication. To establish a Spring RPC connection with Corda, you need to configure your RPC connection using the Kubernetes services.